# Multiplying large values results to negative value

Tags: c#

```
double result = 0.0;
result = 7777 * 7777 * 7777 *7777 ;
```

Instead of getting the result `3658039542829441`, I am getting `-1283042943`. Can someone suggest how to avoid this? I understand the calculation is still under `double` type's range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `7777` is an integer literal. So it is performing integer multiplication. You will need to make these double literals using the `d` suffix. Then it will perform double multiplication.

```
double result = 0.0;
result = 7777d * 7777d * 7777d * 7777d ;
```

Comment: technically only one of them has to be a double and the rest will be implicitly converted

Comment: @RufusL Preferably against one of the first two. It won't work against the last one, for example. But yes, `7777d * 7777 * 7777 * 7777` is sufficient.

Comment: True, it should be the first one.